# How can I find a 2D direction vector of the direction gameobject is looking at

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, quaternions

Here's the important stuff:

```
private RaycastHit2D[] FillRaycastArray()
    {

        List<RaycastHit2D> RaycastList = new List<RaycastHit2D>();

        Vector2 rayOrigin = new Vector2(animalTransform.position.x, animalTransform.position.y);

        animalTransform.rotation.ToAngleAxis(out float angle, out Vector3 axis);

        for (int i = 0; i < genes.sightQuality; i++)
        {
            float rightEyeAngle = angle - (genes.sightAngle / 2 + genes.sightWidth * i);
            float leftEyeAngle = angle + (genes.sightAngle / 2 + genes.sightWidth * i);

            Vector2 rightEyeDirectionVector = new Vector2((float)-Math.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * rightEyeAngle), (float)Math.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * rightEyeAngle));
            Vector2 leftEyeDirectionVector = new Vector2((float)-Math.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * leftEyeAngle), (float)Math.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * leftEyeAngle));

            Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin, rightEyeDirectionVector, Color.red);
            Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin, leftEyeDirectionVector, Color.red);

            int predatorLayer = 1 << 8;
            predatorLayer = ~predatorLayer;

            RaycastHit2D hitR = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOrigin, rightEyeDirectionVector, 20f, predatorLayer);
            RaycastHit2D hitL = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOrigin, leftEyeDirectionVector, 20f, predatorLayer);
            RaycastList.Add(hitR);
            RaycastList.Add(hitL);
        }

        RaycastHit2D[] raycastArray = RaycastList.ToArray();

        return raycastArray;
    }
```

I think the main problem is with converting quaternions to angles and then angles to direction vector for raycasting. I can see something is wrong because object are rotating and the rays rotate but in unrelated way to objects.

Comment: `Transform.forward`.

Comment: I tried it, but I can't change the angle by sightAngle and sightWitdh if all I get is Vector3 pointing forward.

Comment: Well, your question is "How can I find a 2D direction vector of the direction gameobject is looking at?" Which is what `forward` provides.

Comment: You are right, my bad. My first question here.

Comment: @3Dave with a typical setup in a 2D game, `Vector2 foobar = transform.forward` may often result in `foobar == Vector2.zero`, which isn't very useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Transform.TransformDirection`**[*see below]** to convert the eyes "frontward" direction from local space to world space, then use `Quaternion.AngleAxis` to create rotations to the left and right to find the eye directions.

```
Vector2 frontLocalDirection = new Vector2(0.7071f,0.7071f); 
// or whatever the local "front" direction is.

private RaycastHit2D[] FillRaycastArray()
{
    List<RaycastHit2D> RaycastList = new List<RaycastHit2D>();

    Vector2 rayOrigin = animalTransform.position;

    // will be converted to Vector2 later
    Vector3 frontWorldDirection = animalTransform.TransformDirection(
            frontLocalDirection);

    for (int i = 0; i < genes.sightQuality; i++)
    {
        float eyeAngleOffset = genes.sightAngle / 2 + genes.sightWidth * i;

        Vector2 rightEyeDirectionVector = Quaternion.AngleAxis(eyeAngleOffset, 
                Vector3.back) * frontWorldDirection;
        Vector2 leftEyeDirectionVector = Quaternion.AngleAxis(eyeAngleOffset, 
                Vector3.forward) * frontWorldDirection;

        Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin, rightEyeDirectionVector, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin, leftEyeDirectionVector, Color.red);

        int predatorLayer = 1 << 8;
        predatorLayer = ~predatorLayer;

        RaycastHit2D hitR = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOrigin, rightEyeDirectionVector, 20f,
                predatorLayer);
        RaycastHit2D hitL = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOrigin, leftEyeDirectionVector, 20f,
                predatorLayer);
        RaycastList.Add(hitR);
        RaycastList.Add(hitL);
    }

    RaycastHit2D[] raycastArray = RaycastList.ToArray();

    return raycastArray;
}
```

If `frontLocalDirection` would be something like `Vector2.up`, you can just one of `Transform`'s convenience fields such as `transform.up` instead of using `TransformDirection`. E.g.:

```
private RaycastHit2D[] FillRaycastArray()
{
    List<RaycastHit2D> RaycastList = new List<RaycastHit2D>();

    Vector2 rayOrigin = animalTransform.position;

    // will be converted to Vector2 later
    Vector3 frontWorldDirection = animalTransform.up;

    for (int i = 0; i < genes.sightQuality; i++)
    {
        float eyeAngleOffset = genes.sightAngle / 2 + genes.sightWidth * i;

        Vector2 rightEyeDirectionVector = Quaternion.AngleAxis(eyeAngleOffset,
                Vector3.back) * frontWorldDirection;
        Vector2 leftEyeDirectionVector = Quaternion.AngleAxis(eyeAngleOffset, 
                Vector3.forward) * frontWorldDirection;

        Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin, rightEyeDirectionVector, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin, leftEyeDirectionVector, Color.red);

        int predatorLayer = 1 << 8;
        predatorLayer = ~predatorLayer;

        RaycastHit2D hitR = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOrigin, rightEyeDirectionVector, 20f,
                predatorLayer);
        RaycastHit2D hitL = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOrigin, leftEyeDirectionVector, 20f,
                predatorLayer);
        RaycastList.Add(hitR);
        RaycastList.Add(hitL);
    }

    RaycastHit2D[] raycastArray = RaycastList.ToArray();

    return raycastArray;
}
```